# Python: find the first mismatch in two lists

Tags: python, list

Given two lists of the same length, how could one efficiently find the first position where corresponding elements of these lists aren't equal? Basically I need either the index or the two unequal elements.

I'm interested if there exists some laconic "pythonic" solution, without obvious explicit iteration over the lists.

Comment: So - you're ruling out `enumerate(zip(a, b))` then?

Comment: I am deeply interested what you mean by "laconic pythonic solution". What speask against that boring: sort, reduce ( duplicates ), compare - approach? or even enum?

Comment: @Najzero: something with lambdas or using some functions I'm not aware with which will allow to solve the problem in one line. More precisely, I want as few code as possible :)

Comment: Manipulating "positions" or "indexes" is (mostly) non-pythonic. Could you explain how you're using that index?

Comment: @thg435: Well, I'd like to have that both different elements in fact. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @GrigorGevorgyan: if lists are equal, what would be the result? If one list is shorter than another?

Comment: @thg435: they're of the same length, it's stated. If they're equal, let the result be whatever so that I know they're equal

Answer (score 5):

You cannot avoid the iteration over the lists, but you can do it with a comprehension and obtain an elegant solution:

```
next( (idx, x, y) for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if x!=y )
```

If you like something less one-line centric you can split it like this

```
coupled_idx = enumerate(zip(list1, list2))
res = next( idx for idx, (x, y) in coupled_idx if x!=y )
```

EDIT:

as addition, if you need to check the case where the two list can be completly equal, you can add a second parameter to the next function that tells it what return if no index has been found. The most common option is to return None:

```
coupled_idx = enumerate(zip(list1, list2))
res = next( (idx for idx, (x, y) in coupled_idx if x!=y), None )
```

Note that you need to enclose the generator expression between parenthesis because it's not the only argument of the function in this call.

Just to add a little fun, you can also ask the n-th different couple by chaining the expressions. For example this gives you all the couples up to the fifth one (filling with None if the couple is missing)

```
coupled_idx = enumerate(zip(list1, list2))
coupler = (idx for idx, (x, y) in coupled_idx if x!=y)
res = [ next(coupler, None) for _ in range(5) ]
```

EDIT2:

This kind of solution actually create a copy of both list via the zip function. If you need to avoid that you can use the function **izip** from the itertools module instead.

And about the fun part, you can select only certains solutions via the **islice** function fromt he same module

Comment: That was a quick answer, unfortunately it breaks if both lists are equal.

Comment: res = [ (idx, x, y) for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if x!=y ] produces a list of (idx, x, y) elements where there are differences and an empty list when the lists are equal

Answer (score 3):

A functional approach to the 1st problem: Returning the index of the first mismatch

```
>>> from operator import ne
>>> from itertools import compress, count
>>> a = [1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> next(compress(count(), map(ne, a, b)))
2
```

---

A functional approach to the 2nd problem, return the 1st mismatch pair itself instead of the index

```
>>> from operator import ne
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> a = [1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> next(compress(zip(a, b), map(ne, a, b)))
(4, 3)
```

---

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress

> Make an iterator that filters elements from data returning only those that have a corresponding element in selectors that evaluates to `True`. Stops when either the data or selectors iterables has been exhausted. Roughly equivalent to:

```
def compress(data, selectors):
    # compress('ABCDEF', [1,0,1,0,1,1]) --> A C E F
    return (d for d, s in zip(data, selectors) if s)
```

> New in version 3.1.

Comment: +1. This is an interesting variation on the problem. It's a little frail against equal lists as it will raise an exception.

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri OP didn't say how to handle no mismatches. I think the exception is actually pretty clear, so it can just be checked for.  The actual problem is that this will be inefficient for huge lists.

Comment: for python3 you need list(map(eq,a,b)).index(False)

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera I updated my answer to a new approach that works in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: l1=[1,2,3]

In [2]: l2=[1,4,5]

In [4]: next(i for i, (el1, el2) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)) if el1 != el2)
Out[4]: 1
```

Here, `1` is the first index where `l1` and `l2` differ.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
next(i for i, (el1,el2) in enumerate(zip(li1,li2)) if el1 != el2)
```

Or it's equivalent function:

```
def first_diff(li1, li2):
    for i, (el1,el2) in enumerate(zip(li1,li2)):
        if el1 != el2:
            return i
    return False
```

An example

```
>>> li1 = range(32)
>>> li2 = range(32)
>>> li2[10] = 2
>>> next(i for i, (el1,el2) in enumerate(zip(li1,li2)) if el1 != el2)
10
>>> first_diff(li1, li2)
10
```

Comment: I think that this question is a brilliant example of the principle "there should be one way only to do a thing". until now everyone replyed the same same answer with different variable names :)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is an extra default parameter allowed in the next command.  Since filter and zip are generators the following construct touches the minimal number of elements of both lists to determine the first values where both lists are defined at the same index but had different values at that index or returns the default value when no such values exist.

As long as a difference can be found the differing values are returned:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

b=[1,2,7,4,'Hugo']

next(filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1], zip(a,b)),"Value that you choose to represent failure")

Out[91]: (3, 7)
```

When the two lists are equal then the default value is returned:

```
b[2]=3; b[4]=5; b.append(6)

next(filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1], zip(a,b)),"Value that you choose to represent failure")

Out[93]: 'Value that you choose to represent failure'
```

When any other issue causes the search to fail the default value is returned:

```
a=[]

next(filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1], zip(a,b)),"Value that you choose to represent failure")

Out[95]: 'Value that you choose to represent failure'
```

Of course you could assign the generator to a variable and use next repeatedly to find the second or other occurrences.

```
a=[1,2]

b=['fred',1,2.2]

f=filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1], zip(a,b))

next(f,'error')

Out[110]: (1, 'fred')

next(f,'error')

Out[111]: (2, 1)

next(f,'error')

Out[112]: 'error'
```

You can use None as the default to fail silently or use for testing

```
next(f,None)
```

Subsequent calls after falling off the end of the lists do not raise an exception or an error.

```
next(f,'No more')

Out[114]: 'No more'
```